# Use form.getFieldValue to add logic between field without warning

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a Ant Design 4.x.x Form element without multiple Form.Item. I need to implement some logic involving form items' values, for example disabling a field if another one's value equals something, or recalculate select options when a text input changes.

To do so, I create the form using Form.useForm() and use form.getFieldValue() in my functional component body and / or in the returned JSX, like so :

[image: Edit antd reproduction template]

It is working as I expect to, but at startup, getFieldValue usages throw annoying

`` index.js:1 Warning: Instance created by `useForm` is not connect to any Form element. Forget to pass `form` prop? ``

I found that Form functions cannot be used before rendering, and the problem also occured when displaying a form in a Modal [like stated in the docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#Why-is-there-a-form-warning-when-used-in-Modal).

So I feel that I'm missing something on how to correctly add custom logic between fields, or doing some calculation involving fields values in component body.

What would be a correct approach to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `getContainer={false}`, to your modal this will work for you.